# Transpiling Webpack generated ES2015 to ES5

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm very new to Webpack so I might be completely missing something here...

I have Babel set up and working correctly for my own code but Webpack is outputting part of its code in ES2015, so when I come to Ugilfy the bundle I get an error as soon as it hits the first `let`. I can post my config if needed.

Comment: We'll need to see your config. Also if you look at the output code, can you see if it's your own code that contains `let` still, or a `node_module`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your code through a loader in webpack still, without it webpack won't transpile your code to ES5

check https://github.com/babel/babel-loader

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```